Using the lookup ansible.builitin.env on the environment variable PATH does not give the correct value
EDIT This might be a bash issue, so I asked a new question here https://superuser.com/questions/1864359/bash-no-such-file-or-directory-for-executable-in-path
My ansible role does the following:

create a user named weblogic with bash as its shell, a home directory and part of the group weblogic 
unpack JDK into an oracle_home dirrctory, owned by the weblogic user

And finally:
- name: Set
  become: true
  become_user: weblogic
  set_fact:
    newpath: "{{JAVA_HOME}}/bin:{{lookup('ansible.builitin.env', 'PATH')}}"

So newpath is
"/opt/oracle/jdk1.8.0_431/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"

My issue is with this task:
- name : Validate Java
  become: true
  become_user: weblogic
  command: "java -version"
  environment:
   JAVA_HOME: "{{JAVA_HOME}}"
   PATH: "{{newpath}}"
  register: javaver


On ubuntu 24 I get the fact that Java is installed in /usr/bin/java
On SUSE SLES15 I get the wanted Java path

I checked directly as user the weblogic on both hosts:
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/oracle/jdk1.8.0_431
export PATH="/opt/oracle/jdk1.8.0_431/bin:$PATH"

java -version


On ubuntu host:
bash: /opt/oracle/jdk1.8.0_431/bin/java: No such file or directory


On SUSE:
java version "1.8.0_431"




A lookup gives you the information coming from the controller, not the managed node.

Allows you to query the environment variables available on the controller when you invoked Ansible.

Source: ansible.builtin.env synopsis, emphasis, mine.
Here, you want the managed node information, which would be, given that you gather facts in your playbook, ansible_env.PATH.
So, you fact should rather set
newpath: "{{ JAVA_HOME }}/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"


Thanks for clarifiying that lookup is only to get controller values. But this is not what the failure is about. I know because I tried it with ansible_env.PATH before, in this case it is the same value, maybe because my ansible master is also ubuntu, so standard PATH here.
My issue is probably not ansible related, I should have stated that in my question in the first place
